# Java Regex Return Last Word

Tags: java, regex

```
String regex = "(some|text|)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        int start = matcher.start();
        int end = matcher.end();
        System.out.print("Start index: " + start);
        System.out.print(" End index: " + end + " ");
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Hi I would like to return the the full substring including to the end of the word. For example,

if the input is:

```
String input = "I am a texte";
```

I would expect it to return 7 11, I would basically would want to return text upto "e" rather than "t". Is this possible? If so, how can this be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Why use a regexp for this? String has [lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-int-) to find the last index of a delimiter (like space), and it looks like you're not trying to find a "word" but "the substring after the last space" (which are **not** the same thing in many, many languages), so given that, just use:

```
String last = input.substring(input.getLastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

(optionally as two lines with a check to see if `getLastIndexOf` is a sensible position), and done?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following regex instead:

```
  String regex = "(.[^\\s+].*some*.[^\\s]+|.[^\\s+].*text*.[^\\s]+)";
```

This will take all the words that start with some or text. For example: someone.

Comment: How about input of "helpsomeone" I would expect it to return "helpsomeone" i.e. the complete word and "helpsomeone t", I would of expect "helpsomeone" not "helpsomeone t". Is this possible?

Comment: @NameName can you try this:
    String regex = "(.[^\\s+].*some*.[^\\s]+|.[^\\s+].*text*.[^\\s]+)";
I also updated my answer :)